# I'm getting this error during upgrade from 11.04 to latest release

Tags: 11.04

Are there any unknown side-affects on ubuntu for these sorts of errors occurring during upgrade.

To upgrade I did the below command from ubuntu 11.04

```
sudo  do-release-upgrade
```

> Remainder of file ignored Error processing line 2 of
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
>   packages/zope.app.zopeappgenerations-3.5.1-nspkg.pth:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 157, in addpackage
>         exec line
>       File "", line 1, in     KeyError: 'zope'
>
> Remainder of file ignored

---

> Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d.... updating keystore
>   /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts...   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ACEDICOM_Root.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/AC_Raíz_Certicámara_S.A..pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ApplicationCA_-_Japanese_Government.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem
>   error adding /etc/ssl/certs/Buypass_Class_2_CA_1.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/Buypass_Class_3_CA_1.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/CA_Disig.pem   error adding /etc/ssl/certs/Certigna.pem
>   error adding /etc/ssl/certs/certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/CNNIC_ROOT.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ComSign_CA.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ComSign_Secured_CA.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/Cybertrust_Global_Root.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı.pem   error
>   adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/E-Guven_Kok_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Saglayicisi.pem
>   error adding /etc/ssl/certs/ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
>   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
>   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
>   error adding /etc/ssl/certs/Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.pem   error
>   adding /etc/ssl/certs/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/IGC_A.pem   error adding /etc/ssl/certs/Izenpe.com.pem 
>   error adding /etc/ssl/certs/Juur-SK.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA.pem   error adding
>   /etc/ssl/certs/NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem   error
>   adding /etc/ssl/certs/OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GA_CA.pem   error
>   adding /etc/ssl/certs/SecureSign_RootCA11.pem

Comment: You do realize that 11.04 IS the latest release, don't you? Ubuntu 11.10 a.k.a Oneiric Ocelot is currently at Alpha 3 version, which is unstable by definition. You do not want to use it unless you want to test it (i.e. to encounter errors and report them to the developers). If you just want to check out the new release - make a fresh install in VirtualBox, don't upgrade your main machine.

Comment: Can you let me know how to downgrade to 11.04 from 11.10

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/873517) and as such is now closed. Please subscribe to the bug for further details and work arounds